# How to create a folder and upload the selected files in that folder in PHP?

Tags: php, html, server-side

I am trying to create a folder with user given name and to upload the selected files into that folder, but I am only able to create the folder and not able to move the uploaded files into that folder. Please help me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>File upload</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="file">
            <br>
            <label>Enter the folder name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="foldername">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">

        </form>
    </body>
</html>

<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $foldername=$_POST['foldername'];

        $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];

        $tmpname=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

        $result=mkdir($foldername);

        if($result)
        {
            echo "created folder";
        }
        else
        {
           echo "not created folder";
        }
        $row=move_uploaded_file($tmpname,"$result/$filename");
        if($row)
        {
            echo "succesffully uploaded";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "failed to upload";
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You should help your friends here to answer your question. Try posting some logs exemplyfing what you mean by `not able to move the uploaded files into that folder`, isn't there an error or something to point into the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have this:

```
$result = mkdir($foldername);
```

And when you try to move the files you do this:

```
$row = move_uploaded_file($tmpname,"$result/$filename");
```

`$result` will be a boolean based on the success or failure of `mkdir`. I think what you need is this:

```
$row = move_uploaded_file($tmpname, "$foldername/$filename");
```

Comment: I tried and geting this                                                                  created folder
Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\project.php on line 38

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\project.php on line 38

Warning: Division by zero in C:\xampp\htdocs\practice\project.php on line 38
succesffully uploaded

Comment: thanks it really worked  i had to just add the double quotes in this one                     $row = move_uploaded_file($tmpname, "$foldername/$filename");

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Just made few changes to your code. mkdir() needs the foldername and permission to create. Then in the move_uploaded_file function i changed your $ result to $foldername i.e the created folder

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="file">
<br>
<label>Enter the folder name:</label>
<input type="text" name="foldername">
<br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload">

</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $foldername=$_POST['foldername'];

    $filename=$_FILES['file']['name'];

    $tmpname=$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $result = mkdir($foldername,0777);

    if($result)
    {
        echo "created folder";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not created folder";
    }

    $row=move_uploaded_file($tmpname,"$foldername/$filename");

    if($row)
    {
        echo "succesffully uploaded";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "failed to upload";
    }

}
?>
```